# Process.Close() is not terminating created process,c#

Tags: c#, process

I've written a C# application which uses `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to create a process, using

```
 Process P1 = new Process();
 P1.FileName = "myexe.exe";
```

and other proper settings.

I've linked it to an exe file which runs for about 10 minutes. (I'm writing program to measure run-time of programs). Now in between I want to abort the running process. So I wrote in the cancel button's event,

```
 Process.Close();
```

But in the task manager I still see myexe.exe running, it doesn't get aborted. What to do?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Process.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) isn't meant to abort the process - it's just meant to release your "local" view on the process, and associated resources.

I think you mean [Process.Kill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) or [Process.CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx). Personally I'd try to find a more graceful way of shutting it down though.

Comment: and what would that be? to flush all the streams and then send internal abort method if the underlying exe supports it?

Comment: @Anirudh - I think he means "Why do you need to force close the app?". Aborting a process in the middle of execution is usually not favorable because it leads to data corruption.

Comment: I would usually try to indicate to the app "please shut down now" rather than just killing it. If you control the app, you could make it watch for its parent process going away.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think `Process.Kill()` is what you're looking for.