# If I kill a System.Diagnostics.Process with .Kill(), do I also need to call .Close()?

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill

Using C# 4.0, I've created a `System.Diagnostics.Process` that I expect to take a short amount of time to run. If for some reason the process hasn't exited after some amount of time (e.g, I've called `.WaitForExit(timeout)` and the return value was `false`), I need to cleanup. I've decided that it's safe to use `.Kill()` in this particular situation (there are no data structures I'm worried about corrupting).

Given this setup, do I also need to call the `.Close()` method of the Process? If so, should I call `.Close()` before or after `.Kill()`?

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673031/process-close-is-not-terminating-created-process-c `Close` won't abort the actual process, but your view of it and its associated resources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process` implements `IDisposable` via the `Component` class, and the protected `Dispose(bool)` method calls `Close()`.  It is generally considered good practice to dispose of disposable resources when you are done with them, as this will immediately release any resources associated with the class (not having to wait for the GC to run).

So to answer your question:

Yes, please call `Close()` by calling the `Dispose()` method directly or via the C# `using` construct as follows.

```
using(Process proc = CreateProcess())
{
    StartProcess(proc);
    if (!proc.WaitForExit(timeout))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though Close() isn't really that important here, because Kill() will clean up the internal unmanaged resources, +1 for the using block.

Comment: Please rephrase your statement about the disposable - there is no immediate relationship between GC and `IDisposable`. If you call dispose then the class should release all unmanaged resources which the GC cannot cleanup anyway. If you release any managed resource (like killing the reference to them) then this will still have no effect when and how the GC runs.

Comment: @ChrisWue: You are correct, however I didn't want to get into the implementation details of the Disposable Pattern.  When the pattern is implemented correctly, the class finalizer will also call `Dispose()` and clean up any native resources not already released.  In this case, the GC is calling the finalizer, triggering the `Dispose()` call.

Comment: I can't use a using block in this particular context, but accepted for pointing out that process is IDisposable (I hadn't noticed!). Thanks!

Comment: The code in this answer contains a race condition http://stackoverflow.com/q/13564645/57428

Answer (score 12):

`Process.Kill()` and `Process.Close()` both internally call `Close()` on the private SafeProcessHandle object associated with the process. However, `Process.Close()` also explicitly resets several other internal members.

Since Process implements `IDisposable`, you should always call `Close()` on it when you are done, or wrap it in a `using` block.