# How to kill a process without getting a "process has exited" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I use `Process.Kill()` to kill a process. Like this:

```
if( !process.WaitForExit( 5000 ) ) {
   process.Kill();
}
```

and sometimes the process will exit right in between the lines, so control will get inside `if` and then `Kill` will yield an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Cannot process request because the process (ProcessIdHere) has exited.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
//my code here
```

Now wrapping the code into try-catch doesn't seem to be a good idea because `InvalidOperationException` can be called for other reasons.

Is there a way to kill a process without getting an exception in the described scenario?

Comment: Have you tried checking inner exception? Might give you exact exception to handle.

Comment: @Yahya: Yeap, inner exception is null at all times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could P/Invoke [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) passing it [`Process.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx). Then manually evaluating the cause of it (`GetLastError()`). Which is roughly, what `Process.Kill()` does internally.

But note that `TerminateProcess` is asynchronous. So you'd have to wait on the process handle to be sure it is done. <strike>Using `Process.Kill()` does that for your.</strike>

*Update:* Correction, `Process.Kill()` also runs asynchronously. So you'll have to use `WaitForExit()` to wait for termination to complete - if you care.

Frankly, I wouldn't bother. Of course there is always the (remote?) chance that some "arbitrary" `InvalidOperationExcepion` bubbles up out of that line of code, that is not related to the process no longer being there or the `Process` object to be in an invalid state, but in reality I think you can just go with the try/catch around the `Kill`.

In addition, depending on your application, you could consider logging this kill anyway, since it seems some sort of last resort measure. In that case log the actual `InvalidOperationException` with it. If things go strange, you at least have your logs to check why the `Kill` failed.

Having all that said, you might also want to consider catching / handling `Win32Exception` for the same reasons.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `HasExited`:

```
if(!process.WaitForExit(5000)) 
{
   if (!process.HasExited)
   {
       process.Kill();
   }
}
```

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx

Comment: That still has a race condition. `HasExited` may return `false`, but by the time `Kill` executes, the process could be gone - resulting in an `InvalidOperationException` still.

Comment: We're talking fractions of a nanosecond so that seems unlikely, but if that is the case you can't stop it, best you can do is catch the exception.

Comment: "Fractions of nanoseconds" seems like an exaggeration, to be honest. Your process might get preemted, for example, in between the two calls, heck, the box might even hibernate in between coming back up in an "unfortunate order" ;-) But I agree, that catching the exception is the only "robust" solution - if you care. YMMV of course.

Comment: OK true, I just meant it's a very small chance. It's a small chance non the less and should be handled :)