# c# Kill process created by Process.Start("explorer.exe")

Tags: c#

i want open(or create process) directory specific location and close(or kill process)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Process ps;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ps = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\test");
            MessageBox.Show(ps.Id.ToString());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ps.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

but an error occurred
"Cannot process request because the process has exited."

---

edit

i want create process ("explorer.exe C:\test") (click button 1) and kill process made infront of (click button 2).
"click button 1" then "click button 2".

i predict
"Process ps = Process.Start("explorer.exe C:\test");"
can kill like
"ps.Kill()".

but already ps(Process variable) is disappear(killed?) and can't kill created directory process("explorer.exe",@"C:\test").

how to kill i created(or start) explorer.exe process

---

how to kill process created by Process.Start("explorer.exe")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill a process without getting a "process has exited" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564645/how-to-kill-a-process-without-getting-a-process-has-exited-exception)

Comment: @Martheen Not what i wanted and edit question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Process processToKill = Process.GetProcessById(ps.Id);
processToKill.Kill();
```

You can use `Process.GetProcessById()` to get the currently running processes, then `Process.Kill()` to kill a process.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(3000); //Stop responding for 3 seconds

        if (ps .HasExited) //Continue if the process has exited
        {
            //The process has exited
            //Console.WriteLine("The process has exited");
        }
        else //Continue if the process has not exited
        {
            //myProcess.CloseMainWindow(); //Close the main Window
            ps .Kill(); //Terminate the process
        }

Comment: when button2_click, ps.HasExited always return true.

i try to find ps.ID in process list but already killed.
Process.Start("explorer.exe") create another process that's why can't find ps.ID in process list. have any way kill process created by Process.Start("explorer.exe")?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("processname"))
{
   p.Kill();
}
```

or

```
public Process something;
-------------------------
something = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
something.Kill();
```