# C# Window Service and Starting/Stopping cmd.exe

Tags: c#, multithreading, command-line, windows-services

I have a C# Window Service that runs a batch file (.bat) which in turn, executes a java app.  The service runs the .bat file (cmd.exe) with no problem.  However, when I try to stop the window service, the cmd.exe process does not die. A new cmd process is stacked if I start the service again.

How do I kill the running cmd.exe process?

Code:

```
    private const string BATCH_FILE_PATH_APPKEY = "Service_Batch_File_Path";
    private const string BATCH_FILE_DEFAULT = "Service.bat";

    private static Process _proc;
    private static bool _hasStarted = false;

    public AService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _proc = new Process();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            string appDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
            appDirectory = appDirectory.Substring(0, appDirectory.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            string workingDirectory = appDirectory;
            string batchFilePath = string.Empty;
            batchFilePath = workingDirectory + "Service.bat";

            // Make sure it exists


            _proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFilePath);
            _proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            _proc.Start();
            _hasStarted = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString() + "\n\nStack Trace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_hasStarted)
            _proc.CloseMainWindow();
            //_proc.Close(); 
    }
```

TIA,
Alex.

Comment: should _proc.Close() be commented out?

Comment: Ideally you tell your java app to terminate gracefully.  It shuts itself down, the cmd.exe it is running within shuts down and everyone is happy.

Answer (score 0):

_proc.Kill();

See the details in MSDN: [Process.Kill Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

You may find the following link very useful: [Process.Close() is not terminating created process,c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673031/process-close-is-not-terminating-created-process-c)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `_proc.Kill()` in your service's closedown processing?  This is async and you should then call [WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) to give it a decent chance to go away.  Log any failures or exceptions in this logic for investigation.

You should also (for cleanliness) reinstate the `_proc.Close()` after calling `WaitForExit()`, to ensure `Dispose()` gets called properly for the `Process`.  I know your service is about to exit, but this is a good habit and means you are less likely to leak if you decide to manage the child Process more dynamically in future.

Answer (score 0):

_proc.Kill () will work.... but it will orphan your java app.  I have done something similar where a third process was started.  You will also need to know which java process to kill.  To do this, you can use the ParentProcess Performance Counter.

Here are some details on using the [ParentProcess performance counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way).

Also, version of Windows do you plan to deploy this on?  WindowsServer2008 seems to have a cmd.exe and a conhost.exe.  That may pose a problem for you (again one that can probably be resolved by knowing the parent process.