# Trap process.kill in bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I am trying to run a bash script through the process class and do something when I use process.kil()
But it seems that the exit signal isn't triggered so:

A. Is it possible?

B. If it isn't possible is there a way to send a signal to the process?

Script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
Exit(){
echo "terminated">>log.txt
kill $child}
trap Exit EXIT
 daemon &
child=$!
echo $child > log.txt
wait $child
```

C# code:

```
Process script = new Process()
script.StartInfo.Filename = "Script.sh"
script.Start()
//Other stuff
script.Kill()
```

C# script.Kill doesn't seem to trigger Exit() in Script.sh

Exiting through ubuntu's system monitor
does trigger it though.

Edit:

Changing the signal to SIGTERM didn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such signal `EXIT` in UNIX/Linux.  SIGTERM is the closest to what you want and the default signal used by kill.

However, bash has a pseudo-signal called `EXIT`.  It's described in [Bash Manual - Bourne Shell Builtins - trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) which is where you might have gotten confused.

> If a sigspec is 0 or EXIT, arg is executed when the shell exits. If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every simple command, for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function. Refer to the description of the extdebug option to the shopt builtin (see The Shopt Builtin) for details of its effect on the DEBUG trap. If a sigspec is RETURN, the command arg is executed each time a shell function or a script executed with the . or source builtins finishes executing

If you meant to use this, then you should start your script with the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to ensure it is run under the bash shell.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html for a list of all the signals in Linux.

Comment: It does include the #!/bin/bash that was a copy mistake

Comment: I'm guessing this is a C# issue rather than an Ubuntu issue.  I tested your script locally and both ways work.  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952635/what-are-the-differences-between-kill-process-and-close-process might help.